# How much time needed to merge two Active Directory ( >2500 users each)?

Tags: active-directory

Call to IT Company one of them said 3 month, another said 1 hour... And all saing different story about proper merging.
Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: An hour to actually perform the merge, with three months planning perhaps.

Comment: Well you can't `merge` two different AD Forests. You can migrate objects and resources from one to the other.

Comment: How many users? How many workstations? How many servers? What applications are in your environment? Which applications don't support SID History or security translation? Which applications don't support domain migration (Exchange, BizTalk, most System Center products)? Without knowing these details, there's no way to tell you for sure but 1 hour is a ridiculous estimate. Security translation on a busy file server will take longer than that by itself.

Answer (score 7):

Migrating *only* users should take approximately 1 day including the installation and configuration of migration tools.

Migrating just users isn't going to do much. You must also migrate workstations and servers. That is complicated and takes time. Without knowing your environment it's impossible to say how long but 3 months isn't unreasonable.

I plan probably 5-6 AD migrations per year and they are all typically between 4-10 weeks long with the vast majority of that time being planning. If anyone tells you otherwise, be very skeptical.